# Local npm module cannot be found

Tags: npm, webpack

In a React Boilerplate project, I am trying to use a local module, but getting:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/react-sortable-tree-theme-file-explorer/dist/main.js
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/username/Documents/project/node_modules/react-sortable-tree-theme-file-explorer/dist/main.js'
```

Both paths do exist:

```
$ ls node_modules/react-sortable-tree-theme-file-explorer/dist/main.js 
node_modules/react-sortable-tree-theme-file-explorer/dist/main.js
```

and

```
$ ls /Users/username/Documents/project/node_modules/react-sortable-tree-theme-file-explorer/dist/main.js
/Users/username/Documents/project/node_modules/react-sortable-tree-theme-file-explorer/dist/main.js
```

...so I can't figure out what the complaint is. The paths and files DO EXIST. I used `npm link` initially, but that never worked, and so I also tried `npm install ../react-sortable-tree-theme-file-explorer` but it gives the exact same results.

I am importing the package as in:

```
import FileExplorerThemeBase from "react-sortable-tree-theme-file-explorer";
```

Comment: how are you importing it?

Comment: @azium edited question

Comment: Does your question have a typo or does running `ls` on that file actually show `main.j` (without the `s`) ?

Comment: @azium whoops, typo

Comment: is it possible that you're running your project from a different directory than the one where your node_modules are/

Comment: for the record, I just tried installing that package and works fine in a local react project i have

Comment: @azium Definitely the correct directory. Yes, the package itself works fine. After hours of nonsense, I eventually cloned a new copy of my project and everything works again. Somehow `npm link`, or _something_—completely nuked my project :(

Comment: yeah link is only to use packages in directories *other* than ones in your node_modules, typically when you are testing out a package that you haven't published yet or are editing code on a forked version of a package